I would like to add a column rownumber counter based on the InvoiceId only in SQL
Based on the InvoiceId, I would like to count 1 to X and add those line item values next to each order line item.
Desired result wanted.  Adding LineItem column, then counting 1 to X until next InvoiceId



InvoiceId
Item
Description
LineItem




ABC
03944343
SPEAKER
1


ABC
03435555
WAVEMP4
2


XYZ
73843433
GENERATOR
1


XYZ
24543454
PLUG AC
2



Tried using RowNumber() but it is applying it to all records and not restarting to 1 from every new InvoiceId

Try this :
SELECT
InvoiceId,
Item,
Description,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceId ORDER BY Item) AS LineItem
FROM
YOURTABLENAMEHERE

This will Select as you are requesting, note that no changes are made to the data this just presents it in the manner you are requesting (assuming it works for you ).

Shoot now I have to leave my comment up for the historians.  I post a comment for them to try and 5 mins later get ninja answer post with identical post ;/

You can use row_number and partition by. ie:
select InvoiceId, Item, Description,
 row_numbe() over (partition by InvoiceId Order by Description) as LineItem
from myTable;

